# Passing data from one screen to another screen in iPhone using phone gap

Tags: iphone, cordova

I have just started to look into the phone gap.I have created one basic form which taking the data of the employee.I have table view in another screen .I want to pass the employee details to the second screen .I was googling for this purpose.I have found that there are some ways to do this like:

```
  1.Server side post back

  2. Client side URL examination

  3.What's in a window.name = local cross-page session

  4.HTML5 local storage

  5. Cookies
```

But will my phone gap application be 100% native by using these ways? Is there any alternate way or tutorial to pass the data between the screens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you actually mean by "a screen"? If you're talking about a pop-up dialog box or page by jQuery Mobile you can probably serialize the form with jQuery and assign it to a JavaSCript variable.

But if you're changing your "screen" by changing UIView to a different url you can use either:

- File API to store serialized form in a file and load it on the 2nd "screen"
- Storage API to ... actually do the same

I'd go for number one, as it's easier to implement than using SQL and writing loads of additional code.

Search for:

1. jQuery.serialize()
2. PhoneGap File API